# 500:INTERNAL_SERVER ERROR when deploying in vercel

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, vercel, internal-server-error

[enter image description here]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl10Y.png)iam a student trying to build django project and deploy it to vercel since heroku is not free anymore
I followed the tutorial step by step correctly, after deployment, I got 500 internal server error
when I check the log, it gave me

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': No module named 'django'Traceback (most recent call last):
```

after last deployment renaming requirement.txt to requirements.txt i get the following error like in the image instead
I have try to search online for the solution yet none satisfy the similar problem I have, please help, what should i do

Comment: You have to install `django` using `pip install django`

Comment: already install it on my local computer, idk how i can install it on vercel,, how can i make a django project on first time without pip install django at the beginning

Comment: Did you read the rest of the error message? It tells you to use `psycopg2-binary` instead of `psycopg2` in your dependencies.

Comment: already solved, tq for the answer